# How to draw line plus bar chart using highcharts/d3.js or any other chart library?

Tags: d3.js, highcharts, nvd3.js

How to draw line plus bar chart as below using highcharts/d3.js or any other chart library?

So What exactly I am trying to achieve is **"Display bar if no data available for particular time interval"** (here chart says that there is not data available for time interval (17:30-18:30)).

Comment: how do you detect there is/are no data point(s)?

Comment: @rioV8: Either we will not send data for that particular time interval or lets put something json says type: bar for that time interval. So simply question is: **display line for some time interval and display bar for some time interval in same chart.""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can use Highcharts with `plotBands` functionality (which should be more elastic). There is the algorithm implemented on `chart.events.load` which checks whether the `null`s are in `data`, and adds the plot bands to your chart dynamically basing on your current data. Take a look at this code:

```
load() {
    var axis = this.xAxis[0]
    var boundaries = []
    var color = '#55f'

    // Check there are nulls in data. If yes, save the boundaries.
    data.forEach((elem, i) => {
        if (elem === null) {
          if (data[i-1]) { boundaries.push(data[i-1][0]) }
          if (data[i+1]) { boundaries.push(data[i+1][0]) }
        }
    })

    // Create plotBands basing on current boundaries.
    boundaries.forEach((range, i) => {
        if (i % 2) {
          axis.addPlotBand({
            from: boundaries[i-1],
            to: range,
            color: color
          })
        }
    })
 }
```

Additionally, you can add another series to your chart (fake one, with empty data), which will serve to toggling visibility of plot bands. Here is the code:

```
  {
    // Fake series to add toggling visibility of plotbands functionality.
    name: "Zone of Unavailability",
    data: [],
    events: {
      legendItemClick() {
        var bandsGroup = this.chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBandsGroups['bands-0']
        var bandsVisibility = bandsGroup.attr('opacity')
        bandsGroup.attr({
            opacity: bandsVisibility ? 0 : 1
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dzj8bwLm/

**API Reference**:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.legendItemClick

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highcharts/Highstock for this. You can put line and column series into one chart and manipulate them however you like.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
```

and

```
var data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if (i == 10 || i == 11 || i == 12 || i == 13 || i == 14 || i == 15 || i == 16 || i == 17 || i == 18 || i == 27 || i == 28 || i == 29) {
    data.push(null)
  } else {
    data.push([i, Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)])
  }
}

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    ordinal: false,
    labels: {
      format: '{value}'
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: data,
    connectNulls: false,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    pointWidth: 9,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false
    },
    data: [
      [10, 100],
      [11, 100],
      [12, 100],
      [13, 100],
      [14, 100],
      [15, 100],
      [16, 100],
      [17, 100],
      [18, 100],
      [27, 100],
      [28, 100],
      [29, 100]
    ]
  }]

});
```

See this online demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/917uvors/)